# How do I style appbar in this way?

Tags: flutter

[image: prospective design]

How stylize the appbar in this way so that the unselected items will have this gray underline using flutter?

Comment: you mean all items have underline, but selected/unselected have different color?

Comment: yeah, it seem like flutter appbar doesn't have style for  unselected item indicator

Comment: this NOT an AppBar, it's TabBar

Comment: No, you can style your app bar . Use `PreferredSize ` widget in your `appBar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your requirement, I created custom Top navigation bar.

hope you will like it:

Note: Use `PreferredSize` Widget in your appBar.

full Code:

```
void main() {
 runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(

     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home:CustomTopNavigationBar()

   );
 }
}



class CustomTopNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _CustomTopNavigationBarState createState() => _CustomTopNavigationBarState();
}

class _CustomTopNavigationBarState extends State<CustomTopNavigationBar> {
 int tabIndex = 0;
 Color  colorHome = Colors.blue;
 Color  colorMail = Colors.grey;
 Color  colorProfile = Colors.grey;


 changeIndex(int index ){
   setState(() {
     tabIndex = index;
    switch (index) {
      case 0 : colorHome = Colors.blue;
       colorMail = Colors.grey;
       colorProfile = Colors.grey;
       break;

       case 1 : colorMail = Colors.blue;
         colorProfile = Colors.grey;
         colorHome = Colors.grey;
       break;

       case 2 : colorProfile = Colors.blue;
       colorHome = Colors.grey;
       colorMail = Colors.grey;
       break;
      default:
    }
   });
 }




 Widget buildTopNavigationItemWidget( int index, String navigationItemName, Color itemColor){
   return InkWell(
     onTap: (){
       changeIndex(index);
     },
     child: Container(
       height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/ 25,
       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3.5,
       alignment: Alignment.center,
       child:Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           Text(navigationItemName,style: TextStyle(color:itemColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ),),
           SizedBox(height:5),
           Container(
             height: 5,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: itemColor,
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
             )
           )
         ],
       )
     ), 
   );
 }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold( 
     appBar:PreferredSize(
       preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
       child: Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
         child: Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
           children: <Widget>[
             buildTopNavigationItemWidget(0,"Home" ,colorHome),

             buildTopNavigationItemWidget(1,"Mail" ,colorMail),

             buildTopNavigationItemWidget(2,"Profile" ,colorProfile),
           ],
         )
       ),
     ),
     body:  Container(
       color: Colors.white,
       child: tabIndex ==0 ?MyHomeScreen() 
       :tabIndex == 1? MyMailScreen(): MyProfileScreen()
     ),
   );
 }
}

class MyHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.red,
     body: Center(
       child:Text("My Home Screen")

     ),
   );
 }
}

class MyMailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.green,
     body: Center(
       child:Text("My Mail Screen")

     ),
   );
 }
}

class MyProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
     body: Center(
       child:Text("My Profile Screen")

     ),
   );
 }
}
```

OutPut:

[image]